# number of ways in which the board can be restored to a winning configuration

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A game in which there are n*n blocks which can be filled with numbers from 0 to n-1 in some arbitrary way.
The rule of the game is that the board should be filled in such a way that the sum of each row and column should be divisible by n.
Now we say that board in the winning configuration. Now suppose we changed the configuration of the board. Now we are interested to know  to know the number of ways in which the board can be restored to a winning configuration.

My solution

As I know if there is a board of n*n dimension we can fill this board with 0 to n-1 in n^(n-1)*(n-1)

But when I an trying to solve on problem base on this I am getting WA.

[My Solution in Java bigInteger to avoide overflow.](http://ideone.com/R3xLaY)

Comment: You need to add some more details and perhaps, be more clear in what you are looking for. How do we change the configuration? Can all the numbers chosen be 0?

Comment: change the configuration means just exchange the number with each other within the n * n board means SHUFFLE the board.

Comment: So is your question simply, how many winning configurations are there?

Comment: Yes!! absolutely correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the numbers in the top left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix arbitrarily
($n^{(n-1)^2}$ possibilities).

Now everything else is forced: the values in the left $n-1$ entries on the bottom row
are forced by their columns, the values in the top $n-1$ entries on the right row
are force by their rows.

Finally the bottom-right entry is forced by both its row and its column,
but it is forced 'in the same way' both times, because once you
have given it the value as determined by its row, the sum of all entries in the matrix is $0\pmod n$.
The sum of all entries in the left $n-1$ colums is $0\pmod n$.
So the sum of all entries in the rightmost column must be $0\pmod n$.

Since every 'winning matrix' has a top-left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ this gives you all solutions.

So the answer is $n^{(n-1)^2}$.